# can we dynamically allocate memory for static variable in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-variables

Is it allowed to dynamically allocate memory for static variable like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct person
{
   int age;
   int number;
};

static struct person* person_p = NULL;

int main()
{
    person_p = (struct person*)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct person));
}
```

The above code built, but is it really allowed to dynamically allocate memory for static variable?

Comment: And more importantly why are you doing that? You know that functions accept paramters! You don't want to be confused when your program grows!

Comment: what you mean by only the pointer is static?

Comment: The pointer itself is static, but the memory which you allocated via the pointer neither knows nor cares about this.

Comment: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions)  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the 'static' modifier means the pointer is only visible within the current file.  This is a link time attribute.  Other than that detail, it is like any other 'global' variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's valid and allowed. (Unless you're using the pointer as a *placeholder*) You can (and need to) dynamically allocate and `free()` memory to and from the pointer before and after using it.

Rather, please make a note, you [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in C.

Comment: why if it is const, it is invalid?

Comment: @ratzip you cannot change `const`. :-)

Comment: `const`-ness is irrelevant here, and probably is just confusing the issue.

Comment: @PaulR Sir, I thought of bringing up the `const`, as OP had written _dynamic allocation for static variable_, so thought this will clear up the issue. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I don't think `const`-ness is at all relevant - you could still allocate memory dynamically - see e.g. http://codepad.org/fhn2PHg4 (although of course in this instance that would not be particularly useful!).

Comment: @PaulR Sir, I think I'm doing a miserable job in explaining myself . :-( I tried to mean `struct person* const person_p = NULL;` in this case. Hope this is fine.

Comment: In that case though the use of `const` is not analogous to the use of `static` - I would suggest just deleting the following: "The variable is static, not const. So, there is no issue." and keep everything else - then your answer would make sense.

Comment: @PaulR Appriciate the review sir, Updated, can you check once for the clarity now?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. Even though static means there can only be one instance of the object, you still need space for that object. Keep in mind however that anything that is `malloc`'d needs to be `free`'d, so you will want to do that at the end of your `main()` function.

Comment: this is C code.
What you mean "so this structure may be better suited to be in a wrapper function or class where the destruction of it can be tracked."

Comment: Ah yes - you are correct. In that case, you will want to free your structure at the end of the main() function.

Comment: Well, and `static` does not mean you can have only one instance of the object. This *is* one definition, this defines one object (or rather variable, since we're talking C).

Answer (score 0):

Memory isn't "owned" by pointers to it. You can do the following things:

- Dynamically allocate memory
- Make a pointer point to that memory

It doesn't really make sense to say "dynamically allocate memory **for** a pointer".

Any pointer can point to any object (subject to alignment and aliasing restrictions), it makes no difference what the storage duration of the pointer is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is the *pointer* that is static, not the memory it points to.

`static` means two unrelated things:

1. give static memory allocation (memory allocated at start of program, and only released at end of program)
2. give internal linkage (do not allow other compilation units - modules - to access the identifier. Here a variable, could be a function)

In your code, 1. static memory allocation is irrelevant, since the variable is global anyway and as such already has it.

Then, 2. internal linkage does not matter either, because what you are trying to do is inside the module anyway.

In other words, `person_p` is exactly as a usual global variable within your module, and you can do whatever you want to it.

It's only the pointer that is defined by this line of code, so you can dynamically allocate memory elsewhere, and assign the memory address to `person_p` if you wish.